# While loop in a sql-server query using PDO driver PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I´m trying to query to a sql-server database making a while loop through PDO driver from Microsoft for PHP but it is not looping, it only returns one row.

I have tried making the same query inside the Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio and did get the results, I mean, it iterated and get all the rows.

```
Declare @startDate Datetime
Declare @finishDate Datetime
set @startDate = '2019-07-01 06:00:00.000'
set @finishDate = '2019-07-23 06:00:00.000'

Declare @date01 Datetime
Declare @date02 Datetime
set @date01 = @startDate 
set @date02 = @date01 + 1

WHILE @date01 < @finishDate 
BEGIN
    SELECT
        SUM ([col1] * [col2]) as 'val'
    FROM table
    Where [colDateTime] >= @date01 
            and [colDateTime] <= @date02 

    SET @date01 = @date01 + 1;
    SET @date02 = @date02 + 1;
END;
```

When doing the query through PDO I´m only getting one row but I should get like 23 rows.

Comment: you have an error in your sql, there is a `comma` just before `FROM table`

Comment: did you copy past this code ? I guess not since there was this error

Comment: @GuidoG ye I provided that code in example, that is not what I´m using but is the main structure

Comment: Well the result of this code will be one row and one row only, because even if you loop lots of times, the result is each time not saved anywhere, so you only get the result of the last executed query in the loop

Comment: Why do you want to loop in the first place? Loops are notoriously slow in an RDBMS.

Comment: I´m trying to get the values between to dates but looping between this two dates in order to get the sum of each of the days. For example, if I have the dates 20/07/2019 and 23/07/2019 I would like to get the sum of the rows that have the date 20/07/2019, then the sum of the rows that have the date 21/07/2019 and this until getting to the last date that is 23/07/2019.

Comment: drop the loop in the sql code, do something like `where colDateTime >= @date01 and colDateTime < @finishdate` Then you get a resultset you can loop thru in php

Comment: @GuidoG It could be a solution yes to loop in php but the idea is in php only to query and display the results. We save the querys on files and the only thing that makes php is to get the query inside of any file and execute through PDO. That´s why I´m trying to use a while loop inside the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments using a `WHILE` seems like the wrong idea here. Loops are very slow in SQL Server and should be avoided when there a dataset approach is going to give a far more performant result.

If I understand your goal correctly, you can use a Tally Table (I use an Inline here) to create all the dates, and then do everything in one go like this:

```
DECLARE @startDate datetime;
DECLARE @finishDate datetime;
SET @startDate = '2019-07-01T06:00:00.000';
SET @finishDate = '2019-07-23T06:00:00.000';

DECLARE @D int = DATEDIFF(DAY, @startDate, @finishDate)+1;

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (@D) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3), --1,000 days max
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @startDate) AS StartDate,
           DATEADD(DAY, T.I+1, @startDate) AS FinishDate
    FROM Tally T)
SELECT D.StartDate,
       SUM(T.[col1] * T.[col2]) AS Val
FROM Dates D
     JOIN [table] t ON t.colDateTime >= D.StartDate
                   AND t.colDateTime < D.FinishDate
GROUP BY D.StartDate;
```

If you want a row, regardless of if there are values for that date, then change the `JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` (and wrap the `SUM` in an `ISNULL`).

Comment: Let me investigate about Tally Table and see If this is what I need. But I´m not quite sure becouse I should have to create a table and that is not the idea too.

Comment: I don't create a table in the above though, @mathiasminacapilli

Comment: I´m trying to understand your query, where is the table S defined? Becouse you select `SELECT S.StartDate` but I can´t find where is that table S. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Must have miss hit the key, that should be `D`, have corrected, @mathiasminacapilli . Without sample data I didn't test the SQL itself.